# Problem with the installation of dji-osdk on raspberry pi 3 for dji matrice 100

Tags: ros, dji-sdk

I have a raspberry pi 3 with ubuntu mate 16.04 on it and i installed ROS. I'm following this [guide](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/sample-doc/sample-setup.html#ros-onboard-computer) to install the osdk on the raspberry. At point 6, when i type `catkin_make` the raspberry freezes at 94% and doesn't finish the compilation (i think that is because raspberry runs out of ram). How can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding swap space would allow the Raspberry Pi to use the SD Card as extra memory.  Accessing this memory will be very slow, but it can be useful in cases like this.

To create a swapfile you'll need to run these commands.  These instructions assume that the swapfile can be created in the root directory.  You may want to change that depending on your setup to ensure that the file is created on the SD Card.

```
sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
```

To then use the swapfile run the below command.  Note that you'll need to run this command each time you boot.

```
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

To verify that everything went as expected you can use this command to inspect the status of your memory.

```
free -h
```

You'll need to run this command to add the swapfile automatically.

```
echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

For more information, check out this article: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04