# Raspberry Pi Freezes on catkin_make

Tags: linux, ros, dji-sdk

I am trying to install the Onboard SDK V.3.8 to my Raspberry Pi Model B for ROS-Linux. I used the Ubiquity Robotics image that came preinstalled with ROS Kinetic which was working fine with the exception that the Date and Time keeps resetting itself to Feb. 2016. 
I  am attempting to use the OSDK with ROS on the Pi to communicate successfully with one of the DJI Matrice 100 Drones.
Upon trying to build the dji_sdk packages to the catkin_ws using the catkin_make command, my Raspberry Pi freezes up at 92% every time. When I run the command, it goes through all the preliminary steps, yet when it reaches 92% my mouse freezes up, the keyboard stops working, and the time in the bottom left hand corner stops working. After a while of the Pi being frozen, it goes to sleep and I have to start all over again.

I have tried restarting the Pi multiple times, resetting the date and time, and waiting for a long time to just see if it takes long.

```
[91%] Building CXX Object Onboard-SDK-ROS-             
3.8/dji_sdk/CMakeFiles/demo_flight_control.dir/src/demo_flight_control.cpp.o

[92%] Building CXX Object Onboard-SDK-ROS-3.8/dji_sdk/CMakeFiles/demo_mission.dir/src/demo_mission.cpp.o
```

This is where I get stuck on the terminal..

Why cant I install the OSDK? Is there something wrong with the hardware? Or does it have to deal with the files?

Comment: Hazarding a guess... You are running out of RAM and you don't have a swapfile. [Add a swapfile](https://askubuntu.com/q/33697) like you would on a desktop and [set swappiness](https://askubuntu.com/q/103915) to a low number, like 3 or 5. I do it for all my IoT gadgets because I had so many compile and link problems on my dev-boards. Another problem it could be... You don't have a heatsink on the cpu and the processor is overheating and locking up. In that case buy a heatsink or place a fan to blow on the dev-board.

Comment: try    make -j1     or   make -j2     it will slow down but should build

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with the installation of dji-osdk on raspberry pi 3 for dji matrice 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886993/problem-with-the-installation-of-dji-osdk-on-raspberry-pi-3-for-dji-matrice-100)

Comment: I used catkin_make -j1 and it worked fine thank you!